# Call plot() from an R script and get the graph in the output file?

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have created an R script that reads certain data from a file, calls the `summary()` method and then the `plot()` method.

But when I try to run the R script where the commands below are written, in the output file I get the summary, but not the graph.

When I run the following instructions in R manually, everything works perfectly, and I get both the summary and the graph.

Is there a way to get the graph in the output file?

```
m0<-read.csv(file="Myfile", head=FALSE, sep",")
var_m0<-c(m0$ V3)
summary(var_m0)
plot(var_m0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What Justin said. And don't for get the read the FAQ about why your lattice and ggplot2 output fails to show up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell R what kind of output you want and where you want it to go.  Take a look at `?png` for a fairly comprehensive list.  And don't forget `dev.off()` after your `plot()` call!

```
m0 <- read.csv(file="Myfile", head=FALSE, sep",")
var_m0 <- c(m0$ V3)
summary(var_m0)

png('plot.png')
plot(var_m0)
dev.off()
```

If you specifically want the graph in the same output file as the rest of the code, you can look at `knitr` and `sweave`.

Comment: Thanks! This works, and the graph is saved as png file in my working directory. But it is still not printed in the R output file. Is there a way to have the graph there too?

Comment: No, the r output file is plain text.  You can however use something like `knitr` or `sweave` to make a document with code and plot all self contained.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to search a little bit more on knitr and sweave